# Get data from python backend

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I'm running web application and i need to call specific python function, that returns some data. I am trying some AJAX, but I am not sure, how to call specific function. Any advice?

Comment: Same as anything else in Django. Write a URL that points to a view.

Comment: I must be missing something here. Can you provide some example of what you have tried, and also how you managed to wrangle an upvote on a question that defies the most basic requirements (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: here is simple python server https://github.com/vozille/SimpleHTTPServer. you can understand how servers are working. and read about client-server architecture. if you are familiar with node js also you can check this  https://github.com/supun19/NodeServer.git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add to URL patterns (urls.py) your URL:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^/your_url_end$', views.foo, name='foo'),
]
```

or you can do this with `path()` too.

Then declare foo() in view.py:

```py
def foo(request):
    lst = getVarFromBackend()
    response_dict = {'html_0': lst[0], 'html_1': lst[1]}
    return render(
        request,
        'name_of_your_html_doc.html',
        context=response_dict
    )
```

At `responce_dict` you should set name of html var as a key and python var as a value.

And you can use `{{ html_0 }}` and `{{ html_1 }}` at your .html